# Django filtering relation in ListView

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

Given the models

```python
class TaskGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)

class Task(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    group = models.ForeignKey(TaskGroup, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    completed_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

and the list view

```python
class TaskGroupListView(ListView):
   model = TaskGroup
```

I'd like to display the list of task groups with corresponding tasks. The catch is - I only want to show the tasks that have not been completed or have been completed by the user, or if the user as the attribute `user.type == "ADMIN"` set show all groups and all tasks.

Right now I have a template that looks like:

```html
{% for taskgroup in object_list %}
<h1>{{ taskgroup.name }}</h1>
<ul>
    {% for task in taskgroup.task_set.all %}
    <li>{{ task.name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endfor %}
```

I know that I can modify the queryset of a list view by overriding `get_queryset` like:

```python
def get_queryset(self):
    if self.request.user == "ADMIN":
        return TaskGroup.objects.all()
    else:
        ...
```

but I'm not sure how to go about filtering the `Task` relations on the `TaskGroup`s in the else clause.

I've thought about creating a manager subclass for `Task` that can filter based on `.completed` and `.completed_by` that I can use in the template but that seems against the philosophy of Django - I'd like to keep all the logic in the view (this may be way off the mark so please correct me, its been a while since I've touched django/read two scoops of django).

Is there some idiomatic way to do this? Should I discard ListView entirely and write some custom logic? any guidance here is helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`prefetch_related`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) with a [**`Prefetch`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch) that uses a custom filtered queryset like this:

```py
from django.db.models import Prefetch, Q


def get_queryset(self):
    if self.request.user.is_admin:
        return TaskGroup.objects.all()

    return TaskGroup.objects.prefetch_related(
        Prefetch(
            'task_set',
            queryset=Task.objects.filter(Q(completed=False) | Q(completed_by=self.request.user))
        )
    )
```

This will get all the `TaskGroup`s with the related `Tasks`s (in `task_set`) filtered by those that are not yet completed or are completed by the current user.